Another Framework puzzle
Previous Framework
About Framework:

A Framework puzzle is similar to a Fill-in puzzle, except there is no rigid crossword-style grid, however there is a tradeoff with there being fewer hints given for placing numbers in the grid

Goal of Framework:

Fill in the grid with the given numbers

To get the green checkmark $\color{green}✓$:

Solve the Framework


The puzzle

Solve on Penpa+

Puzzle imageNumbers image



CSV (Checksum and Numbers):
====================
=Checksum: 21759821=
====================

Numbers:

=========   ===========   =========   =========   =========   =========
=2-digit=   ==3-digit==   =4-digit=   =5-digit=   =7-digit=   =8-digit=
=========   ===========   =========   =========   =========   =========
24|62       112|231|633   1141        17119       2212299     16144049
34|65       142|335|823   2323        23181       3225280
36|83       187|345|910   3134        31142
41|87       202|526|920               93373
51|97       223|611

CSV (Puzzle):
        +---+---+---+   +---+---+       +---+
        |   |   |   |   |   |   |       |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |       |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |   |||||   |   |   |   |   |||||   |   |   |       |   |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+   +---+---+
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |           |   |   |
    +---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+---+           +---+---+
                        |   |       |   |               |   |
                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+           +---+---+
                |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |           |   |   |
                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                |   |||||   |||||   |||||   |   |   |   |||||   |
                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |||||   |||||   |   |   |
                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                            |   |||||   |   |   |   |   |   |
                            +---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+
                            |   |   |
                            +---+---+


Why not add a digit to the left of each of the 7-digit numbers? That way you get 3 8-digit numbers and nothing can be unconditionally placed at the beginning.

@Laska I try to have 7-digit numbers if I have 8-digit numbers, and try to have less 8-digit than 7-digit numbers

Then have 3 7-digit numbers and 2 8-digit numbers if you must. The point is that it’s dull to be able to write in 8 digits unconditionally imho

Here is the completed grid:

 

We can start with:

 the sole entry of length 8. This gives us an easy slot for 41, 93373, and 17719. 83 is the only possible intersector with 93373, and both numbers of length 7 are now determinable:


 


 202 and 223 are placeable now, as is 31142. This allows the placement of 23181 as the last entry of length 5. 1141 can also be placed intersecting 23181.


 


 The only possible remaining options for the last space in between the two 7-entries is 920/2323, as 1141 has been covered up. We can fill those in, as well as 231 being the last 3-digit entry starting with 2 and 3134 for being the last 4-digit entry (I also filled in some random obvious numbers at this point:)


 

There's two more key deductions to make here:

 112 is the only possible option to connect to the start of 23181, since there are no three-digit options left to connect to the 4 of 142. From there, 611 can be placed as well. In addition, 34 must connect to 3134, since there are no three-digit options that begin with 2. From that, 36 connects to 93373, and the right side of the grid falls apart:


 

and the rest follows:

 


Note that 142 is never actually placed, and there are only 13 3-char slots in the grid. This is still the unique solution though

@emanresuA I assume this was a mistake, but it makes me wonder if a puzzle of this style would be more interesting if there were more red herrings in the number list, so it's harder to place numbers based on being the only entry remaining with X digit/X length and would instead require deeper logic

@ilikecorgis you are right, I accidentally put 142 in the list! Although what I could do (to have the puzzles require deeper logic) is that I could replace a digit in some of the numbers with an X. This way you'd have to think about what number replaces it and use that to fill in the grid.

Completed Grid:

 

To start,

 the eight-digit number can be placed immediately, and there is only one three-digit number (223) that can cross the first digits of the seven-digit numbers, so those can also be placed.
 202, 526, 17119, and 31142 are also forced, and then the other five-digit numbers can also be placed.


 Once this is complete, 1141 is placeable, which forces the number connecting the last digits of the seven-digit numbers to be 920, and fixes the other four-digit numbers. The grid looks like this: 
 and we have 24, 34, 36, 41, 51, 62, 65, 83, 87, 97, 112, 142, 187, 231, 335, 345, 611, 633, 823, and 910 to place.
 231 is fixed, which means that the highlighted cell belongs to a 34, and the 3 above must begin a 36. The numbers these new digits begin can only be 335 and 633, respectively. 24 and 41 attach to the eight-digit number, and we now bring our attention to the top left.


 No three-digit number end in 4, so we can place 112 and then 611 attached to it. 611 must be attached to 65 (and 345 in turn), because placing 62 forces 142, and all three-digit numbers ending in 1 have been exhausted. 823 and 187 are forced in turn, and then 97 and 920 are the only numbers that can finish off the chain. Placing the remaining two-digit numbers is trivial, and 142 remains unplaced.


+1 (great explanation), although sorry you got sniped. Also what I would like to mention is that rot13(lbh pbhyq unir svtherq bhg jurer 41 jrag rneyvre ol abgvpvat gung gurer jnf ab 2 qvtvg ahzore gung fgnegrq jvgu 4 ohg raqrq jvgu n qvssrerag ahzore, fb gung zhfg or pbaarpgrq gb gur 16144049)

You're certainly correct, but since that deduction doesn't lead to anything else, it would feel improper to focus on it right away. I'm sure I didn't when I was doing my initial solve.
